# How To Deep Link to a Specific Location In Apple Health

Tags: javascript, react-native, healthkit, openurl

I'm trying to deep link to the new Vision Prescription page in Apple health. I didn't see any documentation on how Apple health deep linking works, and was able to guess my way into the browse page by going

```
 Linking.openURL('x-apple-health://browse')
```

Does anyone know how they format the urls for deeper pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so apple does not expose any deep links to health app as of now other than x-apple-health://, it rarely mentions a deeplink greater than one level depth so browse seems to be the most you could do, even if you find a deeplink that works by any chance, high probability that it will be broken soon in another update